# Asymptotics of sum with delta function

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How one should  compute the asymptotic of sum in these two form:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k,l,m,n=1}^\Lambda\delta_{k,l+m+n}\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k,l,m,n=-\Lambda}^\Lambda\delta_{k,l+m+n},\end{equation}

where $\Lambda$ is some positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sum is the number of choices of $l,\,m,\,n$ for which $l,\,m,\,n,\,l+m+n$ each range from $1$ to $\Lambda$. These comprise the lattice points in a pyramid; the asymptotic behaviour is of height $\Lambda$ and an isosceles right-angled base of leg length area $\Lambda$, $\tfrac13\cdot\Lambda\cdot\tfrac12\Lambda^2=\tfrac16\Lambda^3$.

The second sum admits a similar treatment. There are asymptotically $(2\Lambda)^3=8\Lambda^3$ choices of $l,\,m,\,n$, of which I'll show two thirds satisfy $|l+m+n|\le\Lambda$, making the sum's asymptotic behaviour $\tfrac{16}{3}\Lambda^3$. In particular, if $L,\,M,\,N$ are $U(-\Lambda,\,\Lambda)$ IIDs $L^\prime:=\tfrac{L+\Lambda}{2\Lambda}$ are $U(0,\,1)$ IIDs, and [by the $n=3$ case of the Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Special_cases)$$\begin{align}P(|L+M+N|\le\Lambda)&=P(1\le L^\prime+M^\prime+N^\prime\le2)\\&=\int_1^2\tfrac12(-2x^2+6x-3)dx\\&=\left[-\tfrac13x^3+\tfrac32x^2-\tfrac32x\right]_1^2\\&=\tfrac23.\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you please show me how did you derive the result?

Comment: @sultana See edit.

Comment: Thanks,@ J.G.!  If I follow your reasoning correctly, would  this be true 
 \begin{equation}
 \sum_{k,l,m,n=1}^{\Lambda}\delta_{k+l,m+n}\rightarrow O(\Lambda^2)
 \end{equation}
 
  \begin{equation}
 \sum_{k,l,m,n=-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}\delta_{k+l,m+n}\rightarrow O(2\Lambda^2)
  \end{equation}?

Comment: @sultana No, those sums are also $O(\Lambda^3)$, because we still have $O(\Lambda^4)$ choices for $k,\,l,\,m,\,n$ to loop over, with a $O(1/\Lambda)$ proportion thereof matching whaetver equation is desired.